# Skewed frustum not distorting scene

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, 3d, frustum

I was trying to achieve a 3D perspective of a scene as per the position of the user. I read about asymmetric frustum approach to achieve the distortion when the user is not looking from the axis.

The code I used to do off-axis projection is:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(frustumLeft, frustumRight, frustumBottom, frustumTop, frustumNear, frustumFar);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0, 0, headZ);
drawWalls();
```

When the user is looking at the axis, the scene comes out to be drawn as:
[image]

When the frustum has been shifted off-axis, the scene comes out to be drawn as:
[image]

However, what I expected to have come somewhat along the line of the following image (achieved by using gluLookAt and assymetric frustum). 
[image]

For the above program I used assymetric frustum only to specify the viewing volume and on changing the parameters (2nd image) only made the scene to look like a little translated (no distortion). I am wondering if this is the correct behavior or if I'd missed something and not getting the distortion (like 3rd image) in the scene which should have been there. Shouldn't skewed frustum alone be giving me the distorted scene output?

Comment: The problem in the second image is that you didn't change the position of the eyes. As I posted in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723674/skewed-frustum-off-axis-projection-for-head-tracking-in-opengl), the border of the screen needs to remain in the same 3D positions within the frustum. So if you move the head to the left, you have to move the frustum to the right, and vice versa.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg : Moving the eyes by the same amount by which the frustum has been shifted from the center gives me the required effect (i.e. correspondence between near plane and screen plane is not lost). And moving the 'eyes' is going to happen with `gluLookAt` which won't rotate the whole scene itself and gives that effect of correct off-axis projection (change of perspective as per user's position)

Comment: `gluLookAt` does rotate the scene, the matrix M [in the documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) is composed of unit vectors f, s, and u, which are the axes of the rotated coordinate system. You only need to move the camera, which is equivalent to translating the rest of the scene, only in the other direction. I'll post some screenshots in the other question.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg : Thanks. I'll check the screenshots out there as well. Meanwhile, I checked again with a simple test with gluLookAt and I wasn't getting the rotation. My understanding could be wrong but the viewing transformation generated when eyeX = lookAtX, eyeY = lookAtY, eyeZ =0, eyeZ = -1 doesn't seem to be giving that rotation. Using those parameters, am I not just moving the camera and rotating it?

Comment: What happens if you move the eye more and more to the left and closer to the cube? I would expect the top right corner of the cube not to be on the same on-screen height anymore as the top left corner, because it is further away from the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

frustum is like perspective view except the fact that perspective view is always symmetric
if you make frustum asymmetric it will show you same effect as in image 2.
now what happened to the 2nd image is that it has more view volume to its left side as compared to the right side, so if the image is in the middle it will shift to the right.
example as shown here [image-frustum](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/gl_transform15.png) more view volume on right as compared to left so it will look like object is pushed towards left because right volume is now occupy more space.

if we change the camera position or where it sees then our object's symmetry changes.
Just as if you move your head left or right on the x axis, your computer screen's symmetry will change.feel like bit skewed.

Comment: Does that mean to achieve distortion (as in 3rd image), I would have to make use of `gluLookAt`? On using `gluLookAt` along with glFrustum, I was able to get the required outut of perspective from a different view, so I guess that is the right way to go?

Comment: [link](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/gl_transform15.png)
this is how asymmetric frustum looks like

Comment: Umm.. Perhaps there's a bit of confusion here I am facing. I refer to the distortion as the result that is obtained in 3rd image, which actually gives the effect of changing the scene perspective on looking from a different point. However, as you pointed in the comment above, I would have to make an asymmetric frustum which would distort the 3d world. In the post above, 2nd image, where I actually have done that i.e. an assymetric frustum why doesn't it look like a distorted 3d world? Or is the word 'distortion' that I am misusing here?

Comment: sorry my mistake for the above comment i scrambled few things. what happened in your 2nd image is that it has more view volume on the left side as compared to the right side, hence the object shifted to the right side.now camera can see more volume on the left side as compared to the right side as show here [link](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/gl_transform15.png)
in this image more volume on the right and less on the left so if the object in middle will shift to left.
if you will will change the camera position or its look then object will change its symmetry.

Comment: just as if you move your head left or right on the x axis your computer screen symmetry will change.feel like bit skewed.