# Rotating an asymmetric frustum

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, 3d

In my program, I am defining an asymmetric frustum in the projection matrix which changes as per user's position. In case of a plane with all z values at the same position, my program works fine. However, if the viewing plane is a bit rotated (rotation along Y-direction), I then rotate the camera by doing a `glRotate` in `ModelView` matrix.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(topLeftX, bottomRightX, bottomRightY, topLeftY, camNear, camFar);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(xHeadPosition, yHeadPosition, zHead, xHeadPosition, yHeadPosition, zHead -1 , 0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(400, 0); //Rotating with the right side of the plane as the pivot
    glRotatef(yRotation, 0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(-400, 0);
```

However, I want to do the same in the projection to keep the MV matrix clean. I tried to do the same as follows:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(400, 0); // Pre-multiplication here as opposed to post-mulitplication in MV matrix
        glRotatef(yRotation, 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef(-400, 0);
glFrustum(topLeftX, bottomRightX, bottomRightY, topLeftY, camNear, camFar);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
        gluLookAt(xHeadPosition, yHeadPosition, zHead, xHeadPosition, yHeadPosition, zHead -1 , 0, 1, 0);
```

However, the above does not give me the required output and it doesn't seem to be rotating the projection plane to make the viewing plane prependicular to the user/camera. How can the projection plane be rotated such that it be becomes prependicular to the user?

Comment: That won't simply work that way.

Comment: Why don't you use the link in [this answer to another question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17451331/872616)? It gives you everything you need to position a screen at an arbitrary position and orientation in space.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg : I couldn't find the part where arbitrary orientation is handled in that code. Other than that, that answer helped a lot. Can you specify where exactly in the code is the arbitrary orientation handled? P.S I am thinking on the lines of multiple screens where some of them might not have same Z for all four corners.

Answer (score 1):

I think you really need to understand what glLoadIdentity does. It discards whatever is on top of the matrix stack and replaces it with identity. Between those glLoadIdentity calls those glTranslate and glRotate have no effect whatsoever (except consuming some CPU time and memory bandwidth). Similar the glLoadIdentity before the gluLookAt renders nil what glFrustum did.

My suggestion: Grab a book on linear algebra, notably matrix math, work through it. Then you grab a book about 3D graphics math, to understand how to put the abstract concepts learned from the book before to some use.

Then you should familiarize yourself with the OpenGL vertex transformation pipeline.

Finally understand that there is no point in having a "clean" modelview matrix. What you have in your first code snippet is what you want: A base matrix on which to build upon.

---

#### Update

Okay, here you have a small misconception in your thought:

```
glLoadIdentity();
// Pre-multiplication here as opposed to post-mulitplication in MV matrix
glTranslatef(400, 0);
glRotatef(yRotation, 0, 1, 0);
glTranslatef(-400, 0);
glFrustum(topLeftX, bottomRightX, bottomRightY, topLeftY, camNear, camFar);
```

What makes you think you should pre multiply here? The transformation chain is

```
p_view = MV · p_local

p_clip =  P · p_view
```

you can contract that into

```
p_clip = P · MV · p_local
```

The separation into modelview and projection matrix is not done for transformation of positions, but for transformations of normals. That later step is just required for illumination purposes. But for this to work, the projection matrix must contain only the projection part, but not any viewport placement. Or in other words, this *glTranslate → glRotate → glTranslate* part doesn't belong there. Anyway, if you decide "oh, I don't need illumination" (for whatever reason, you'd have to place it *after* the call to glFustum. Why? Because that's why:

In the first case your modelview MV and projection P matrices are

```
MV = I · gluLookAt · glTranslate · glRotate · glTranslate

 P = I · glFrustum
```

since `I · x = x` we can omit that I. So the position transform would be

```
v_clip = P · MV · v_local =

       = glFrustum · gluLookAt · glTranslate · glRotate · glTranslate · glRotate · v_local
```

Regarding just the position (but not the normals) you can put the split between modelview and projection transform at any point in the above transformation chain. In your desired case (which doesn't make a lot sense BTW) that would be right before *v_local*. So

```
P = glFrustum · gluLookAt · glTranslate · glRotate · glTranslate · glRotate
```

But like I already told: This only works if you don't need the normals to be properly transformed.

Comment: I forgot to write `glMatrixMode` in the second code since I ust typed it in and didn't copy paste. I am familiar with `glLoadIdentity` and transformation pipeline from Model->View->Projection->Screen as well. But that missing `glMatrixMode` made it look like I am doing gluLookAt call in projection matrix. I hope the code makes sense now but I am trying to achieve the same rotation I achieved with first code to build an adaption matrix for one of my requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Got it more clearly but I noticed that even if I place the `glTranslate(..); glRotate(..); glTranslate(..)'` after glFrustum as you mentioned, it doesn't still give me any output. The rotation matrix multiplication was in accordance with the explanation I got here http://bit.ly/1b4b2fC to rotate the projection for the screens that are different i.e. for screens which are rotated, I should opt for glFrustum() * rotation * translation. Is this wrong? How do I rotate the projection in my case ideally such that it becomes prependicular to the user?

Comment: @user1240679: Well, technically the rotation and the translation are in order, but to be honest, doing it that way is quite cumbersome. This much easier done by simply writing down the right matrices. But that's a topic I probably better write in a dedicated tutorial, because it requires several intermediary levels of knowledge, which simply don't fit into a StackOverflow answer (also my cat just occupied my graphics tablet, so I can't draw pretty pictures right now).